# ArcGIS Server Services containing process crashed

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server

I have several services deployed on ArcGIS Server 10.1, one of them has the error:

> Services containing process crashed. ServiceName.GPServer instance has
>   crashed.

Any suggestions for correction?

If I need to uninstall ArcGIS Server is there a way to keep the services created or do I need to create again?

Comment: Have you enabled verbose logging to see if you can get more info from server logs? Also has the error log folder been populated with recent logs? If you're running this server in a corporate network, it could be that anti virus software may be impeding server processes. As for backups try looking at the following help doc...http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Backing_up_and_restoring_your_ArcGIS_Server_site/015400000619000000/

Comment: ArcGIS 10.1 has been retired for a while now. I remember 10.2 as being far more stable, but given the burden I was placing on my dev box (and the not strictly supported shortcuts I was taking), I had to rebuild every few weeks and reinstall twice a quarter. Once a service had been corrupted, it rarely bounced back (though the uncorrupted ones usually survived). Once I got to 10.3, the install was rock solid, and rebuilds only occurred with new software releases. You should always keep a backup of the MXDs used to create services or the Python used to make the MXDs.